# How do I copy a file without overwriting an existing file?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I have the below code that copies a text file from a directory to another with overwriting the file if exists

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirs[0]);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string fname = file.Substring(dirs[0].Length + 1);
            string dist = Path.Combine(dirs[1], fname);
            File.Copy(file, dist, true);
        }
```

What I'm looking for is to copy the file to the destination directory without overwriting, but keep both files. As in Windows for example, a copy of a file named "test" many times would be

```
test
test - Copy
test - Copy (2)
test - Copy (3)
text
text- Copy
text- Copy (2)
text- Copy (3)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your

```
File.Copy(file, dist, true);
```

To

```
File.Copy(file, dist, false);
```

If you have looked in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static void Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite )
```

> Parameters
>   sourceFileName Type: System.String The file to copy.
>   destFileName Type: System.String The name of the destination file.
>   This cannot be a directory.
>   overwrite Type: System.Boolean true if the destination file can be 
>   overwritten; otherwise, false.

And add exception handling in way of changing the destination file name and trying to Copy until it's successful

UPDATE 1
You can try to use code like above. This seems to me a shorter than the one by your provided link. I have not tested this for any possible cases, but for simple cases like copying "tmp.txt" while there exist "tmp - copy.txt" and "tmp - copy (1).txt" this is working.

UPDATE 2 Yeah sorry, there was a little bug using .Select and only than .Count i have fixed it

```
        string sourcePath = @"c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\tmp\test1\";
        string destinationPath = @"c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\tmp\test2\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string fname = file.Substring(sourcePath.Length);
            string dest = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fname);
            if (File.Exists(dest))
            {
                var existingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath);
                var fileNum = existingFiles.Count(x => x.Substring(destinationPath.Length).StartsWith(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname)));
                dest = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dest) + " copy" + (fileNum > 1 ? " (" + (fileNum - 1) + ")" : "") + Path.GetExtension(dest));
                File.Copy(file, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(file, dest);
            }
        }
```

The result of repeating copy of same folder to same destination folder after 5 times is the following:[image]

Comment: @FSm yeah sorry, forgot to add about adding handling

Comment: @FSm if you didn't imagine how to do I can write the code

Comment: S.Petrosov, you are right. Actually, a relative solution can be found here https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/613427/How-to-a-copy-text-file-without-overwrite-existing . However, some new ideas would helpful

Comment: @FSm I have updated my answer but as you can understand the global idea how to this is close to the one I have provided before.

Comment: It may works for one time file creation, I have created a method that deals with each time the program run, then the file been copied as in the OP

Comment: S.Petrosov, sorry for late replay. your method is very elegant.. However, if the directory has two files say (art, politic). After some times run, it gives `art, art - copy (3), politic, politic- copy (4)`, while it should be `art, art -copy, art - copy (2),politic, politic - copy, politic - copy (2)`. See my update and  please review it.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string extention = ".txt";
        string originalFileName = string.Format("test{0}", extention);
        string duplicateFileName = "test";
        string changedName = duplicateFileName;

        int count = 1;
        while (File.Exists(changedName + extention))
        {
            changedName = string.Format("{0} - Copy ({1})",
                duplicateFileName, count++);
        }
        File.Copy(originalFileName, changedName + extention);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtsource.Text) &&
        Directory.Exists(txtsource.Text) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdestination.Text) &&
        Directory.Exists(txtdestination.Text))
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(txtsource.Text);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        var filtered = files.Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));
        foreach (var file in filtered)
        {
            try
            {
                string tempPath = Path.Combine(txtdestination.Text, file.Name);
                var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(tempPath);
                while (true)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(tempPath))
                    {
                        if (!Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath).EndsWith(" - copy"))
                        {
                            var existingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(txtdestination.Text);
                            tempPath = Path.Combine(txtdestination.Text, fileNameWithoutExtension + " - copy" + fileExtension);
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath).EndsWith(" - copy") ||
                            Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath), @" ^.*- copy \(\d+\)"))
                        {
                            var existingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(txtdestination.Text);
                            var fileNum = existingFiles.Count(x => x.Substring(txtdestination.Text.Length).StartsWith(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath)) &&
                                                                   (Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath), @" .*- copy$") || Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath), @" .*- copy \(\d+\)$")));

                            tempPath = Path.Combine(txtdestination.Text, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath) + (fileNum >= 1 ? " (" + fileNum + ")" : "") + Path.GetExtension(tempPath));
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                file.CopyTo(tempPath, false);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)

            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: For long blocks of code like this, it's best to add an explanation of it or to at least comment the important part.